# Is there a single word for "Use the contribution of"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word (or more elegant word) for "Use the contribution of"? Ok, some more context:

I'm looking to make a more-dynamic alternative of:

> The team will be composed of analysts.

Too static, there is no notion of contribution. So I'm trying to use contribution is my sentence.

> The team will use the contribution of analysts.

I'm not a native speaker, but this sounds bad to my ears. Trying to formulate it as an active sentence:

> Analysts will contribute to the team.

Which is not good because the original meaning has been lost (I wanted to indicate the composition of the team.)

Other attemps I tried that failed:

> The team will be powered by analysts.

(Not sure this this correct English, or if the meaning is respected)

Could a native speaker suggest a correct formulation that contains the two main ideas I want to convey?

1. This team will be composed of analysts (and analysts only)
2. People will not be seating on their chairs, but be contributing to the team success

Comment: The team will employ the services of analysts, perhaps?

Comment: Hi @gyin!  I like your thought process and that you gave us a pretty good idea of what you need.  +1 for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would say

The/A team of analysts...

To give the impression that they are actually doing something I would use "active"

An active team of analysts will do XYZ

This is much better stylistically than

The team will comprise/consist of X active analysts... (where X is a number that seems to be required)

None of your proposals sound right (in part) because of the indeterminism of the analysts.
This construction is designed to give us definitive information that is then lacking.

Comment: Thank you. I had to make a few adjustments to make it fit within context, but your proposal worked best in my context.

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest:

> The team will be composed of contributing analysts.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native speaker but, "utilisation" is a common term used  in the workplace to denote that you will "use the contribution" of a resource. Resources include human resources. So you could say "analysts will be utilised (for xyz purpose)".